# how to implement socket.io-stream in angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, socket.io, socket.io-stream

how can i implement socket.io-stream in angular. we can use socket.io-stream in web client using [browsify](https://github.com/browserify/browserify) https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-stream?tab=readme-ov-file#browser. but not work in angular.

i tried to import socket.Io-stream.js
`import * as SS from './socket.io-stream';`
after browsify package but it not work. and gives much error
so how can i use it?

Comment: "but it not work. and gives much error so how can i use it" - Please, post the error. Just edit your question, and add the error you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some research i found my question's answer by following

step 1: add cdn into the index.html file

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io-stream/0.9.1/socket.io-stream.min.js" integrity="sha512-LTN7WQKvmCiOWbwxE4XRu3NCRqLzkFo28vBDHVhAyKjhmorNGjtvFxQgbvAttO31Ij6An4AIXU4GVaYOC0eNpQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

step 2: declare ss in ts file where you want ss object

```
declare ss: any;
```

note: declare ss just after all imports.

and after that you can use like

```
const stream = ss.createStream()
```